Function method to get Internet Connection type in KMM
Help me write code to get the internet connection type (Cellular Data or Wifi) for android and iOS in KMM.
I know we need to platform-specific code but I am not able to get any resources regarding this problem

For android, you can get ConnectionType in Android from ConnectivityManager
For iOS, you can check SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName and
SCNetworkReachabilityFlags

Thanks for the resources, I worked on that and in Android I will be needing Context to call the service functionalities, how can I get Context of android app in Android Module of KMM

suspend fun isInternetAvailable(client: HttpClient): Boolean {
    return try {
        // Perform a simple GET request to a known website (e.g., Google)
        client.get<String>("https://www.google.com")
        true // Connection is available
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        false // Connection is not available
    }
}

